# How I can install AsteriskNOW on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, asterisk, vps

I have a question about asterisk, I know that I can install asterisk on EC2, but my questions is:

Its possible install [AsteriskNOW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digium#AsteriskNOW) on Amazon EC2? if not, why? and where its the best possible server or solution for install this

thanks

Comment: AsteriskNOW on AWS EC2 seems a no-brainer.  Or not?  Re-inventing the wheel versus forging a new path?

Answer (score 2):

AsteriskNow is a complete distribution based on CentOS available as an ISO file.  There doesn't appear to be an EC2 AMI available for it so you would have to build an image yourself.

[Here's an overview of the process for Oracle Linux](http://www.rittmanmead.com/2014/09/obiee-sampleapp-in-the-cloud-importing-virtualbox-machines-to-aws-ec2/) which boils down to:

- Install AsteriskNow onto a VirtualBox or VMWare instance locally.
- Configure all the EC2 specifics (This is the fiddly bit)
- Export that virtual machine as a VMDK.
- Copy the VMDK to S3
- Import the VMDK to an EBS volume and launch on Amazon EC2.

Before you export you will have to make sure AsteriskNow has a [kernel that supports EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/use-your-own-kernel-with-amazon-ec2/). In CentOS this would be the Xen kernel but I don't know if Asterisk would supply one, which means compiling.  The [PV-GRUB docco](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UserProvidedKernels.html) also covers a lot of what can and can't be used on EC2. If it doesn't work out of the box it will take some Linux smarts to figure it all out.

It will probably take a number of exports/imports to get it running. Once you have it up on EC2 you can turn that instance into an AMI to quickly create clones in the future without going through the whole export/import process.

Comment: HIgly not recommended use AsteriskNOW, in current moment it outdated and have alot of security bugs. You can install pbxinaflash.net on top of centos 6 AMI running on EC2. There are nothing special in that install, not require any inport/export etc.

Comment: `virt-install` cannot just install AsteriskNOW from ISO?

Answer (score 0):

can you not just download the ISO directly?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~/iso$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~/iso$ wget -v https://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk-now/AsteriskNow-1013-current-64.iso
--2017-11-17 05:52:53--  https://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk-now/AsteriskNow-1013-current-64.iso
Resolving downloads.asterisk.org (downloads.asterisk.org)... 76.164.171.238, 2001:470:e0d4::ee
Connecting to downloads.asterisk.org (downloads.asterisk.org)|76.164.171.238|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1343909888 (1.3G) [application/x-iso9660-image]
Saving to: ‘AsteriskNow-1013-current-64.iso’

AsteriskNow-1013-curr 100%[======================>]   1.25G  1.79MB/s    in 9m 54s  

2017-11-17 06:02:48 (2.16 MB/s) - ‘AsteriskNow-1013-current-64.iso’ saved [1343909888/1343909888]

ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~/iso$
```

https://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk-now/